# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS is here, yet I still don't see upgrade prompt?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, point-release

So I've been waiting for 22.04.1 hoping I will be able to upgrade my system. If I understand correctly 22.04.1 is out.

Yet `do-release-upgrade` still claims there is no version to upgrade to from my 20.04 LTS.

Is this normal? How long it can take before my system notices new version? Or maybe it's still not marked as "stable" for upgrading from 20.04 LTS?

When I google for information I find a lot of articles claiming I should be able to upgrade which only adds to my confusion...

Comment: What's the value that has been set in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`?  Is it `lts`?  I think `do-release-upgrade` should have prompted you before the point release came out (i.e., when 22.04 first came out).

Comment: @Ray it's lts. But 22.04.1 was supposed to be update for current LTS releases.

Comment: Yes, it should be.  I suppose you can do a `sudo apt update` and also check your sources.  Maybe your system will "notice it more" if you switch to another server.